# Element scrollHeight not updating after setting inner element's display to 'none'?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I am trying to create a bootstrap type navbar using angularJS 1.3.14 for learning purposes. I have a navbar, and navmenu, navMenuToggle and navDropDown directives. The navMenu is a logical grouping for the toggle and dropdown menu.

```
<navbar>
    <div class="navbar-brand">Brand</div>
    <collapse-icon></collapse-icon>
    <nav-menu>
        <div class="nav-button" ng-click="toggle()">Toggle Button</div>
        <nav-dropdown>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">First Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Second Link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav-dropdown>
    </nav-menu>
</navbar>
```

The problem is that when I 'expand' the navbar, and double click the toggle button, the navbar's height does not adjust back when the menu is closed.

Here is a JS Fiddle (make the window < 798px): http://jsfiddle.net/5st3h30j/3/

The `toggle()` function in the navMenu contracts and expands the dropdown via setting the `display` to `none` or `block` and then it lets the navbar know via `$scope.$parent.$parent.$broadcast('dropdownClosed')` which then triggers the setting of the height to the new scroll height.

navDropdown Controller:

```
        $scope.toggle = function () {
            if ($scope.open) {
                console.log('closing dropdown');
                $scope.contract();
                $scope.open = false;
                $scope.$parent.$parent.$broadcast('dropdownClosed');
            } else {
                $scope.$parent.$parent.$broadcast('dropdownOpening');
                $scope.expand();
                $scope.open = true;
                $scope.$parent.$parent.$broadcast('dropdownOpened'); // broadcast from navbar's scope to reach all dropdowns
            }
```

navbar:

Controller:

```
        $scope.$on('dropdownClosed', function () {
            $scope.adjustHeight(); 
        });
```

Link Function:

```
            scope.adjustHeight = function () {
                console.log('adjusting height');
                var height = element.prop('scrollHeight');
                element.css('-webkit-transition', 'height 0s');
                element.css('height', height + "px");
                navbarCtrl.expanded = true;
            }
```

I dropped in console.logs and the dropdown is definately contracted before the height is adjusted.

Note: I am aware this does not work for big screens. I will add some if-statements later. Better ways to do this are appreciated but I am also quite desperate to know why adjustHeight succeeds when expanding but not contracting.

Comment: Nothing happen when I click on the thing in your jsfiddle, even with a super tiny screen.

Comment: On my computer the bar expands and shows 'toggle button' which can then be clicked again to expand and show 'first link' and 'second link.' You don't need too tiny a screen. If the `collapseIcon` is shown to the far right, it should be enough. I just tested in IE and firefox and it works. I'm not sure why its not working on your device.

Comment: hmmm seems to work if the window is more than ~780px but should be less than 798? that's tight. Anyway, what are you trying to do with this `element.prop('scrollHeight');`,  couldn't you just let the height adapt itself like regular HTML/CSS? Otherwise you can compute it mathematically, but this scrollHeight looks not reliable

Comment: Not if I want to make the height open smoothly. Here is an example of my end goal. I'm not sure how they do it. http://getbootstrap.com/examples/navbar/

Comment: Aha! Thanks a lot. As you said, I let the browser take care of it by setting it to 'auto.' Please post an answer? I'm tired and going to sleep now and will accept tomorrow morning. I will also leave this open if anyone reading this can tell me what is wrong with what I was doing and why it wasn't working originally because I am still very curious. Will upvote anyone that can answer.

Comment: alright, posted as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reliably use `element.prop('scrollHeight')` to get the height of the element. This property is meant to give you the position of an element on which you have scrolled upon - definitely not what you need.

Try using `element.height()` at wrost, but I would recommend to avoid setting this height via Javascript and instead find a pure CSS way.

Using `height: auto` (which is default) should adjust the height by itself.

Also, do not write `element.css('-webkit-transition', 'height 0s')` from the code, but simply add some class to your element and use CSS again:

```
.my-class {
  transition: height 200ms;
}
```

Note that I set the transition to 200ms, a transition of 0s seems useless, why setting a transition at all?

Hope all of this could help you work around your problems.